# cómo truncar una tabla con sql dinámico mediante variable bind oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

¡Hola! necesito realizar un truncado de tabla mediante SQL dinámico, este debe ser con un procedimiento de almacenado con un cursor y variable bind para que sea el usuario quien ingrese la tabla a truncar. Cuando compilo, todo está bien, pero cuando ejecuta el SQL dinámico, arroja el siguiente error: "nombre de la tabla no válido".

````
create or replace procedure sp_sql_dinamico(p_nombre_tabla varchar2) as
    v_id_cursor INTEGER;
    v_filas INTEGER;
    v_truncate VARCHAR2(50);
begin

    v_id_cursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

    v_truncate := 'truncate table :b_nombre_tabla';

    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_id_cursor,v_truncate, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(v_id_cursor,':b_nombre_tabla', p_nombre_tabla);

    v_filas := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH (v_id_cursor);  

    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_id_cursor);

end;

begin
    sp_sql_dinamico(:b_nombre_tabla);
end;```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure sp_sql_dinamico(p_nombre_tabla varchar2)
as
    v_id_cursor INTEGER;
    v_filas INTEGER;
    v_truncate VARCHAR2(60);
begin
    v_truncate:='truncate table '||p_nombre_tabla;

    v_id_cursor:=DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(v_id_cursor,v_truncate, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

    v_filas:=DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH(v_id_cursor);  

    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(v_id_cursor);

end sp_sql_dinamico;
```